# Content div not resizing as needed

Tags: html, css

I've got the following three divs in my webpage!

```
#header { //top div
height: 60px;
min-width: 1024px;
background-image: url(../images/header_bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
display: block;
}

#content { //middle div
min-width: 1024px;
min-height: 585px;
}

#buttons { //bottom div
min-width: 1024px;
height: 120px;
max-height: 120px;
background-color: rgba(229, 229, 255, 0.76);
}
```

[image: example picture]

as shown in the image, when the resolution changes, the content div does not extend! how can I make the content div expand to fit the page size! without getting any vertical scroller!

Comment: So are you saying you want the buttons to stick to the bottom of the browser window? In that case, you probably want what's called a "sticky footer".

Comment: let's say I opt for a sticky footer by setting the position absolute to bottom. Then the content would miss the buttons div and will continue to expand it self! isn't it?

Comment: No, sticky footers involve much more than that. Positioning the footer absolutely isn't a good method, and that won't cause the content area to grow taller, anyway. Here is a good guide to doing a sticky footer properly: [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?171943-CSS-FAQ-Tips-etc-Please-read-before-posting!&p=1239966#post1239966)

Answer (score 1):

given you have a fixed height footer and header, you can achieve what you want with the following html and css

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
html, 
body {min-height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}

#wrapper {padding:60px 0 120px 0; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;}
#content {min-height:100%;}
#header {margin-top:-60px; height:60px;}
#buttons {margin-bottom:-120px; height:120px;}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2WcPG/)

Answer (score 0):

Say you want your header and buttons to have a fixed width you can do this with your content:

```
#header.row { height: 60px; top: 0; }
#content.row { top: 60px; bottom: 120px; border: 1px solid black;}
#buttons.row { height: 120px; bottom: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hx5v/

Comment: The header and buttons are ok! but the issue is that when the resolution change, the content doesn't get resized accordingly and the buttons don't get pushed down to the bottom! how can I fix that issue?

Comment: isn't that what I posted above...?

Comment: I found a way, if you don't mind having a fixed height footer and header. I'll edit my post